# chicken scheme - how do i temporarily capture data sent to standard output

Tags: unit-testing, chicken-scheme

I have a procedure that calls `(display "foo")`

I want to write a unit test for it, to confirm that it's sending the correct data there but `display` sends its input to Standard Output:

```lisp
(define (display x #!optional (port ##sys#standard-output))
  (##sys#check-output-port port #t 'display)
  (##sys#print x #f port) )
```

Question:
In other languages I might redefine standard output as something that just writes to a variable, and then set it back after the test. Is that the correct thing to do in chicken ? If so, how? If not, then what is the correct thing to do?

Note: passing something else in to display as a second parameter isn't an option because i'd have to alter the method I'm unit testing to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `port` is an optional second argument which **defaults** to standard output.

You can do one of two things to send it to a string.  The first way is to create a string port and pass it to `display` as the optional argument to use instead of the standard output port:

```
(use ports)
(call-with-output-string
  (lambda (my-string-port)
    (display "foo" my-string-port)))
```

The second is to temporarily bind the current output port to a string port:

```
(use ports)
(with-output-to-string
  (lambda () (display "foo")))
```

The second way is mostly useful when you're calling procedures that don't accept a port argument, like `print`, for example.

You can find this in the [manual section about string ports](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20ports#string-port-extensions).

Comment: Excellent. The second is what I need for the test, but I was wondering about the first too. Thanks.